# How to disable magic searching after I move targets of shortcuts in Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows, search, shortcuts

When I move or delete the target of a shortcut and click the shortcut afterwards windows kindly starts searching and guessing.

How to disable this on Windows Server 2003? I'd prefer a quick error condition.

How to do the same on windows xp, maybe there is no difference?

*Edit:* For windows shortcuts see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link#Microsoft_Windows

> Windows shortcuts maintain their
>   connection even when the target is
>   moved, unlike symbolic links. Windows
>   XP will search for a broken link's
>   target before offering to delete it.

*Edit2:* From the accepted answer:

Quoted from http://www.tomstricks.com/how-to-disable-the-ntfs-file-system-tracking-of-broken-shortcut-links-in-windows/ :

Navigate to this registry key:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Policies\Explorer`

Add a new DWORD value and name it NoResolveTrack, set the value to 1.

Will only be effective after the next reboot. Applies only to target files on NTFS partitions. FAT partitions do not have this ID tracking and search capability.

You can also do this for NTFS at a Group Policy level by selecting `Do not use the tracking-based method when resolving shell shortcuts`  in the `UserConfiguration\AdministrativeTemplates\Start Menu & Taskbar` group policy branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How To Disable the NTFS File System Tracking of Broken Shortcut Links
>
> SUMMARY
>
> If you disable a shortcut, the NTFS File System in Windows XP and
>   Windows 2000 automatically attempts to locate the shortcut destination
>   by searching all paths that are associated with the shortcut. This
>   step-by-step article describes how to prevent this behavior from
>   occurring.
>
> Disable the Tracking of Broken Shortcuts
>
> WARNING: If you use Registry Editor incorrectly, you may cause serious
>   problems that may require you to reinstall your operating system.
>   Microsoft cannot guarantee that you can solve problems that result
>   from using Registry Editor incorrectly. Use Registry Editor at your
>   own risk.
>
> To prevent the NTFS file system from tracking alternate paths for a
>   broken shortcut link, make the following changes in the registry:
>
> 1. Start Registry Editor (Regedit.exe).
> 2. Navigate to the following key:
>      HKEY_CURRENT_USERSoftwareMicrosoftWindowsCurrentVersionPoliciesExplorer
> 3. On the Edit menu, click New, and then click DWORD value.
> 4. Type NoResolveTrack for the Value name, and then press ENTER.
> 5. Double-click the new value, and then set it to 1.
> 6. Click OK.
> 7. Quit Registry Editor.
>
> You can also prevent this behavior at a Group Policy level by
>   selecting the Do not use the tracking-based method when resolving
>   shell shortcuts check box in the following location:
>
> User ConfigurationAdministrativeTemplatesStart Menu and Taskbar group
>   policy

Source: [How To: Disable The NTFS File System Tracking Of Broken Shortcut Links In Windows](https://expertreplies.com/how-to-disable-the-ntfs-file-system-tracking-of-broken-shortcut-links/).

Comment: this link is even much better than the ss64.com link from the other answer

Answer (score 1):

I found this: http://ss64.com/nt/shortcut.html

> Shortcut: NTFS file system tracking
>
> If a shortcut to a file breaks because
>   the destination file has moved, then
>   by default Windows will attempt to
>   automatically locate the shortcut
>   destination by performing a search
>   (this only applies to NTFS
>   partitions). To turn this off - add a
>   DWORD value of 1 to the registry:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer NoResolveTrack=1
```