# Why does Windows 7 change the properties of my shortcuts?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable magic searching after I move targets of shortcuts in windows server 2003?](https://superuser.com/questions/141719/how-to-disable-magic-searching-after-i-move-targets-of-shortcuts-in-windows-serv)

I've got a shortcut on my desktop for an executable on a mapped drive. Lets say the Z: drive. If I change the mapping of the drive from say Z: to S: and then double click on that shortcut, my executable will open because Windows changed the properties of that shortcut to run from the S: drive. While this may be handy in some circumstances, its NOT for me. How can I prevent Windows from modifying my shortcut to what it thinks I want.

Thanks

Comment: See: http://superuser.com/questions/141719/how-to-disable-magic-searching-after-i-move-targets-of-shortcuts-in-windows-serv

Comment: That's what i was looking for! Ill mark your answer if you make it an official answer.

Comment: Just vote up the answer on the other question. ;)